# What happens when provision profile expires?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, profile

When I add my provisioning profile to Xcode through the Organizer, I can see that the profile is set to 3 month duration only.

My question is, if I deploy an app to the test device using the above profile. And after 3 months of the app installed on the device, if I open the app would it work or the app will fail to load due to the expired profile?

How does it usually work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The app will fail to launch due to the expired profile.  You will need to renew the provisioning profile and install that renewed profile on the device; or rebuild and reinstall the app with another non-expired profile.  A developer also has to keep their $99 developer enrollment from expiring in order to keep being able to renew or create new provisions.

Ad Hoc profiles have longer expiration dates.  But if you want an app that doesn't expire, the only alternative for stock OS iOS devices is to have it approved by Apple and then download it from the App store.  After you download the app, you have the option of removing it from sale.

Comment: Provided the profile has the same application identifier and *certificate*, it works. AFAIK, builds signed with old certificates are not compatible with new profiles, which is slightly annoying (especially since the maximum validity of the profile is the expiry date of the certificate!). It's also possible to re-sign an old build with a new profile (which is what "Build and Archive" is supposed to do for you, I think).

Comment: People reading this, don't get confused, the answer is for test apps. As in other questions on StackOverflow, it is noted that apps that were already released thru the App Store will continue to function after a provisioning profile has expired: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380740/what-happens-to-an-ios-app-when-a-provisioning-profile-expires